# php loop for search and replace in a string

Tags: php, loops, str-replace

Hye! This is my first question here, so sorry in advance if I don't get it right.

I want to insert pictures from a gallery in a description text by using #pic1# (#pic2# and so on) in the text and replace it with

Here is the code:

```
<?
$myString =$art[0][page_text];
$pics=mysql_query_assoc("select * from pages_galerie where id_page='".$id_page."'");
$count= count($pics);
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
$search='#pic'.$i+1.'#';
$img=$pics[$i][pic];
$newString = str_replace($search, "<img src=".SITE_URL."pics/medium/".$img.">", $myString);
}
?>
```

It doesn't work!
What do I do wrong?

Comment: Can you give an example of what's in `$pics`?   (Edit the question and copy/paste some of it in there)

Comment: If `$id_page` stems from a GET/POST variable, that's asking for a SQL injection. Also, you forgot quotes in the array key on this line `$img=$pics[$i][pic];` it should be `$img=$pics[$i]['pic'];`

Comment: just a small off-topic point, but the short-form `<?` tag is not recommended. It is better to always use the long form `<?php`. (many PHP servers have the short tags disabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
http://codepad.org/2NBlkDN9

```
<?
$myString =$art[0][page_text];
$myString = '#pic1# #pic2#';
//$pics=mysql_query_assoc("select * from pages_galerie where id_page='".$id_page."'");
$pics = array(
   array('pic' => 'TEST1'),
   array('pic' => 'TEST2'),
   array('pic' => 'TEST3'),
);
$count= count($pics);

$newString = $myString;
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
$search='#pic'.($i+1).'#';
$img=$pics[$i][pic];

$newString = str_replace($search, "<img src=".SITE_URL."pics/medium/".$img.">", $newString);
}
echo $newString;
?>
```

You were performing the replacement in `$myString` and storing it in `$newString` everytime. Hence only the last replacement had any effect on the final output. I have initialzed `$newString` with `$myString` and performed the replacement in `$newString`.